# Permissions in ElasticSearch

Tags: arrays, elasticsearch, intersection

Given a set of documents similar to the following:

```
{
    "value": "Some random string here",
    "permissions": ["job.view", "special.permission"]
}
```

We want to be able to create a search that'll allow us to pass an array of permissions to match against, for example, we might want to pass in

```
["job.view", "foo.bar", "pineapple.eat"]
```

as the permissions.

The document should only return in the search if all the permissions listed in the document exist in the set passed in as part of the query.

Not fussed whether we have to change the document layout, or the query, but, we're currently restricted to not being able to use the Scripting API (due to AWS).

Comment: Just to clarify, all `permissions` from your document must be present in your query? Even If you'd add random stuff to `["job.view", "foo.bar", "pineapple.eat", "random", "random.more", "much.more.random"]` it would still pass through?

Comment: So, for example, the above query wouldn't match the example document, because it doesn't have `special.permission`.  Adding `special.permission` would make it pass (even though it also contains `foo.bar` and `pineapple.eat`).  So, yes, it'd pass even with extra stuff *in the query*

Comment: 100% of the permissions on the document must be in the query, but the query can contain extra permissions that don't exist in the document.

Comment: The solution to this would be pretty similar to [the one you've just put a bounty on](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31156108/match-all-values-in-a-nested-array-using-elasticsearch) except that it's easier since you don't have sub-arrays. You don't need to iterate over sub-arrays, just check that the intersection between the `permissions` array and your search array has the same length as the `permissions` array.

Comment: @Val any way to do this without scripting?

Comment: @Mez the permissions you have in the query and the ones you have in the documents have any sense of order? Are they ordered in some way?

Comment: Oh, I didn't grab your last sentence, sorry (are you talking about the new Amazon Elasticsearch service?). I'm attempting a different answer.

Comment: @AndreiStefan not really, but they could be!

Answer (score 0):

There is a convoluted way to do this which requires you also index the number of permissions in the document, i.e. if the document contains two values in the `permissions` array (like in your example) then you'd also include the field `permissions_count: 2`.

Then your query would contain as many `bool/should` queries as there are permissions permutations in your search array. For instance, in your search array you have 3 permissions `["job.view", "foo.bar", "pineapple.eat"]`, then you need to check the following conditions:

1. `permissions` contains all three permissions and `permissions_count: 3`
2. or `permissions` contains two of the three permissions (three combinations) and `permissions_count: 2`
3. or `permissions` contains only one of the three permissions (three possibilities) and `permissions_count: 1`

So when checking for 1 permission, you'll have 1 query in your `bool/should`. For 2 permissions, you'll have 3, for 3 permissions you have 7, etc..

The full query is shown below:

```
{
   "query": {
      "bool": {
         "should": [
            {
               "bool": {
                  "must": [
                     {
                        "terms": {
                           "permissions": ["job.view", "special.permission", "pineapple.eat"]
                        }
                     },
                     {
                        "term": {
                           "permissions_count": 3
                        }
                     }
                  ]
               }
            },
            {
               "bool": {
                  "must": [
                     {
                        "terms": {
                           "permissions": ["special.permission", "pineapple.eat"]
                        }
                     },
                     {
                        "term": {
                           "permissions_count": 2
                        }
                     }
                  ]
               }
            },
            {
               "bool": {
                  "must": [
                     {
                        "terms": {
                           "permissions": ["job.view", "pineapple.eat"]
                        }
                     },
                     {
                        "term": {
                           "permissions_count": 2
                        }
                     }
                  ]
               }
            },
            {
               "bool": {
                  "must": [
                     {
                        "terms": {
                           "permissions": ["special.permission", "job.view"]
                        }
                     },
                     {
                        "term": {
                           "permissions_count": 2
                        }
                     }
                  ]
               }
            },
            {
               "bool": {
                  "must": [
                     {
                        "term": {
                           "permissions": "special.permission"
                        }
                     },
                     {
                        "term": {
                           "permissions_count": 1
                        }
                     }
                  ]
               }
            },
            {
               "bool": {
                  "must": [
                     {
                        "term": {
                           "permissions": "job.view"
                        }
                     },
                     {
                        "term": {
                           "permissions_count": 1
                        }
                     }
                  ]
               }
            },
            {
               "bool": {
                  "must": [
                     {
                        "term": {
                           "permissions": "pineapple.eat"
                        }
                     },
                     {
                        "term": {
                           "permissions_count": 1
                        }
                     }
                  ]
               }
            }
         ],
         "minimum_number_should_match": 1
      }
   }
}
```

As you can see it's a bit convoluted only to check for three permissions...

I would maybe approach this problem from a different perspective and come up with another field (or set of fields) that would contain a bitset of permissions or cleverly chosen integers for each permissions, but I haven't fully thought-out this one yet.

Another solution would be to leverage Shield and document-access control instead of storing the permissions within the documents themselves.

Comment: Doesn't exactly do what I need.  The permissions we're sending could be a list of say, 100 permissions, and we only want to return if all the items in the document exist in those 100.  Kind of like a should, but with a minimum matches set to the count of permissions in the doc.  Your query seems to have to permute every combination?

Comment: Bitset was an option - but we potentially have more than 32/64 permissions.

Comment: Yes, that's why I used the adjective `convoluted`! Without using scripting and simply indexing an array of permissions strings, I'm afraid there are not too many options. A bitset is not limited to 32/64 permissions, it just depends on how many bits you pick ;) Have you looked into Shield and document permissions?

Comment: But it gets awkward assigning numbers to them/doing math after 64 :) (assuming a singular one).  And - I had a brief look at shield - and, as far as I can tell, it'd not work directly with AWS stuff - so we might aswell setup our own ES server, on which we can do scripting?

Comment: There's no easy solution to do operations on sets (which is basically what you need for permission matching) without [using scripting as depicted here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31156108/match-all-values-in-a-nested-array-using-elasticsearch).

Comment: @Val I have the same problem to solve as Mez. I see the scripting solution but would like to avoid if possible. Would changing a nested array to a parent-child paradigm bring about a different solution or would the same problem occur?