# Filtering Field with multiple values

Tags: elasticsearch

How would I approach the following problem: 
I want to filter on a field which contains multiple values(eg. ["value1", "value2", "value3"]).

The filter would also contain multiple values (eg. ["value1", "value2"].
I want to get back only the items which have the same field value as filter, eg. field is ["value1", "value2"] and the filter is also ["value1", "value2"]

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: This answer might help (even though it is in groovy, which was before painless): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31156108/match-all-values-in-a-nested-array-using-elasticsearch/33650088#33650088

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the somewhat-recently added (v6.1) [terms_set query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-terms-set-query.html) (which [Val](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4604579/val) references on the question he linked in his comment) is what you want.

`terms_set`, unlike a regular `terms`, has a parameter to specify a minimum number of matches that must exist between the search terms and the terms contained in the field.

Given:

```
PUT my_index/_doc/1
{ 
    "values": ["living", "in a van", "down by the river"],
}
PUT my_index/_doc/2
{
    "values": ["living", "in a house", "down by the river"],
}
```

A `terms` query for `["living", "in a van", "down by the river"]` will return you both docs: no good. A `terms_set` configured to require all three matching terms (the script `params.num_terms` evaluates to `3`) can give you just the matching one:

```
GET my_index/_search
{
    "query": { 
        "terms_set": {
            "values": {
                "terms": ["living", "in a van", "down by the river"],
                "minimum_should_match_script": {
                  "source": "params.num_terms"
                }
            }            
        }
    }
}
```

**NOTE:** While I used `minimum_should_match_script` in the above example, it isn't a very efficient pattern. The alternative `minimum_should_match_field` is the better approach, but using it in the example would have meant a couple of more PUTs to add the necessary field to the documents, so I went with brevity.

Comment: This helped a lot, only problem is we are currently below version 6.1 so the implementation will have to wait until we upgrade. Thank you.